# What is the fastest way to create one a multilevel pandas dataframe made from multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Basically I am doing the following and I think there is probably a faster way than doing pd.concat and df.append in every loop?

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for (key, data, date) in data_tuples:
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Price', 'Quantity'])
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
    df = pd.concat([df], axis=0, keys=[timestamp])
    df = pd.concat([df], axis=0, keys=[key])
    final_df = final_df.append(df)

final_df.index = final_df.index.rename(['symbol', 'time', 'row'])
final_df['Price'] = final_df['Price'].apply(float)
final_df['Quantity'] = final_df['Quantity'].apply(float)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to avoid append and concat at each step you could:

1. create iterator from your data of tuples
2. apply method on the iterator to parse dataframe and prepare it to the required format
3. apply pd.concat once on the list of dataframes.

of course, you need to modify the logic to meet your desired output but i hope it gives you a grasp of the approach.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime



data_tuples = (("1", {"Price": [1,2], "Quantity":[1,2]}, "20:20:20"), ("1", {"Price": [3,4], "Quantity":[3,4]}, "20:20:30"))


def parse_values(data, date):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Price', 'Quantity'])
    df["date"] = date
    return df


df = pd.concat([parse_values(data,date) for _,data,date in data_tuples])
```

Comment: This speeded it up a lot...from about 3.5 seconds to 0.65 seconds! thanks